# Getting 'Reply already sent or deferred' error on Discord interaction (djs)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am currently building a trivia system and would like to reply every time a user submits an answer to a trivia question. However, I have the following problem with the script below:

```
const datahandler = require("../../dataHandler")
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const xml = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest
const triviahttp = new xml()


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('trivia')
        .setDescription('Answer various trivia questions and earn some quick Jumobos!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.deferReply();
        const difficulties = ['easy', 'medium', 'hard']
        await triviahttp.open('GET', "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple&difficulty=" + difficulties[Math.floor(Math.random()*difficulties.length)])
        await triviahttp.send('');
        triviahttp.addEventListener('load', async function() {
            const data = JSON.parse(triviahttp.responseText)
            const choices = ["", "", "", ""]
            const allanswers = [data.results[0].incorrect_answers[0], data.results[0].incorrect_answers[1], data.results[0].incorrect_answers[2], data.results[0].correct_answer]
            let randomanswer = Math.floor(Math.random()*allanswers.length)
            choices[0] = allanswers[randomanswer]
            await allanswers.splice(randomanswer, 1)
            randomanswer = Math.floor(Math.random()*allanswers.length)
            choices[1] = allanswers[randomanswer]
            await allanswers.splice(randomanswer, 1)
            randomanswer = Math.floor(Math.random()*allanswers.length)
            choices[2] = allanswers[randomanswer]
            await allanswers.splice(randomanswer, 1)
            randomanswer = Math.floor(Math.random()*allanswers.length)
            choices[3] = allanswers[randomanswer]
            await allanswers.splice(randomanswer, 1)
            randomanswer = Math.floor(Math.random()*allanswers.length)
            let prize = 0;
            if(data.results[0].difficulty == 'easy') {
                prize = "10"
            } else if(data.results[0].difficulty == "medium") {
                prize = "20"
            } else if (data.results[0].difficulty == "hard") {
                prize = "50"
            }
            const triviaembed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#34faa4')
                .setTitle("<:chat:924420173040066641> Trivia question!")
                .setDescription(`Answer the following question to win some Jumobos. The harder the question, the more Jumobos you may earn! You have 10 seconds to answer the following question. **Reward:** <:jumobo:941073795232460951> ${prize} \n\n **Q:** ${data.results[0].question} \n\n **A.** ${choices[0]} \n **B.** ${choices[1]} \n **C.** ${choices[2]} \n **D.** ${choices[3]} \n\n Please respond with an answer, **A-B-C-D**.`)
                 await interaction.reply({ embeds: [triviaembed], fetchReply: true })
                const filter = m => m.content === "A" || m.content === "B" || m.content === "C" || m.content === "D" && m.author.id == interaction.user.id;
                const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({filter , max: 1, time: 10000})

                collector.on('collect', message => {
                    message.delete()
                    collector.stop()
                })

               collector.on('end', async collected => {
                   if(collected.size === 0) {
                       await interaction.followUp("You have ran out of time!")

                       return;
                   }
                   let convertlettertochoice = '';
                   if(collected.first().content == "A") convertlettertochoice = "0";
                   if(collected.first().content == "B") convertlettertochoice = "1";
                   if(collected.first().content == "C") convertlettertochoice = "2";
                   if(collected.first().content == "D") convertlettertochoice = "3";
                   console.log(convertlettertochoice)
                   
                   if(choices[convertlettertochoice] == data.results[0].correct_answer) {
                       await interaction.editReply({content: "Hooray! You got this one correct. You have been awarded <:jumobo:941073795232460951> **" + prize + "**.", embeds: []})
                   } else {
                       await interaction.editReply({content: "You got this one incorrect. Yikes! :pensive:", embeds: []})
                   }
                   setTimeout(async () => {
                       await interaction.deleteReply();
                   }, 5000);
               })
            
        })
    }
};
```

I get the following error in the console:

```
C:\Users\kkost\Desktop\BristoSystems\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:90
    if (this.deferred || this.replied) throw new Error('INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED');
                                             ^

Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
    at CommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\kkost\Desktop\BristoSystems\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:90:46)
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kkost\Desktop\BristoSystems\src\commands\economy\trivia.js:46:36)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED'
}
```

I have tried multiple solutions from many other fellow coders but couldn't figure it out so far. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On line 46 you are trying to reply, change this to editReply.

Change: `await interaction.reply({ embeds: [triviaembed], fetchReply: true })`

To: `await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [triviaembed] })`

Also it might be worth making your code more tidy, then you won't have these issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! After executing the command for a second time, everything runs twice (embed replies, data requests, etc.) Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: For more context, it's trying to edit all the interaction embeds created from the past.